# Porting "import gobject" to use GObject-Introspection. (PyGTK to PyGI and GTK 3)

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, pygi, porting

I've been trying to port a library from PyGTK to use GI and GTK3. The problem is I can't find any resources specific to the gobject imports, but only for GTK. I was hoping that if someone would translate the following for me, I would get a grasp of how to do this stuff. The GTK things itself seems to be fairly well documented, but I can't find anything about this.

```
__gsignals__ = {'cell-edited' : (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE,
    (gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, 
    gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT)), 'selection-changed' : 
    (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, (gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT,))}
```

My assumption was, since I couldn't find any specific documentation, that it would be a matter of changing the name of the constants, but I can't find any replacements.

Comment: Really trying not to be rude here but don't you think your question goes better in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)? Most of the ppl here wont have a clue about what you are asking :(

Comment: In this case, the library in question is Quickly Widgets as well, so I think it should be relevant here. :)

Comment: I had a [related question](http://askubuntu.com/q/306078/31658) and [the solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/306082/31658) was to install some libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think I've cracked the code after dir()-ing everything I could find in the GObject class =>

`G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST` is found in the `GSignalFlags` enum, which translates to `GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_FIRST`. This is consistent, so `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_ID` found in the enum `GSignalMatchType` translates to `GObject.SignalMatchType.ID`.

Not entirely obvious, but easy enough once you know what to look for.

Answer (score 4):

As per previous comments, the translation you asked would be as follows:

```
from gi.repository import GObject

__gsignals__ = {'cell-edited': (GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_LAST,
                                GObject.TYPE_NONE,
                                (GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT, GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT)),
                'selection-changed': (GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_LAST, GObject.TYPE_NONE, (GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT,))}
```

However, according to my own experience, some python types are somehow internally mapped to their `GObject` counterparts (or at least, it works as if they were), that is, `object` is mapped to `GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT` and `None` to `GObject.TYPE_NONE`. Hence, I find the following version more straightforward:

```
from gi.repository import GObject

__gsignals__ = {'cell-edited': (GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_LAST,
                                None, (object, object, object, object, object)),
                'selection-changed': (GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_LAST, None, (object,))}
```