# Import python bindings for meta Tracker introspection

Tags: python, search, tracker

When I try to run the metaTracker introspection examples or import the Tracker module in iPython console I get an import error.  Googling for this particular error message doesn't turn up anything except the patch that created these supposedly working examples for meta Tracker in 2012.

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
IPython 0.13 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import gi
In [2]: from gi.repository import Tracker, GObject
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Tracker
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0b29c3277539> in <module>()
----> 1 from gi.repository import Tracker, GObject

ImportError: cannot import name Tracker
```

And what is a typelib and how do I install or import one for Tracker?

Answer (score 2):

To search for any libraries that might be needed for tracker I did:

```
sudo apt-cache search tracker | grep meta
```

which turned up the following leads:

```
libtracker-sparql-0.14-0 - metadata database, indexer and search tool - library
libtracker-sparql-0.14-dev - metadata database, indexer and search tool - development files
libtracker-sparql-doc - metadata database, indexer and search tool - API documentation
mktorrent - simple command line utility to create BitTorrent metainfo files
tracker - metadata database, indexer and search tool
tracker-dbg - metadata database, indexer and search tool - debugging symbols
tracker-explorer - metadata database, indexer and search tool - developer tool
tracker-extract - metadata database, indexer and search tool - metadata extractors
tracker-gui - metadata database, indexer and search tool - GNOME frontends
tracker-miner-fs - metadata database, indexer and search tool - filesystem indexer
tracker-utils - metadata database, indexer and search tool - commandline tools
```

I'd already done a `sudo apt-get install tracker*` so I wasn't missing any of the core utilities or debug symbols so the next obvious lead was...

```
sudo apt-get install libtracker-*
```

which installed ever thing I could possibly need:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-tracker-0.14 libtracker-extract-0.14-dev libtracker-extract-doc libtracker-miner-0.14-dev libtracker-miner-doc libtracker-sparql-0.14-dev libtracker-sparql-doc
```

and fixed the import error:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
IPython 0.13 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import gi
In [2]: from gi.repository import Tracker, GObject
In [3]: %run tracker/examples/introspection/python/all-async.py
('http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nco#default-contact-me', 75L)
('http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#roi-content-face', 73L)
('http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#roi-content-pet', 72L)
('http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#roi-content-focus', 74L)
('http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#roi-content-barcode', 76L)
('http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#roi-content-undefined', 78L)
```